# Kotlin default parameter ordering

Tags: kotlin, default-parameters

Does anyone know why the call to `method1` does not compile whereas the call to `method2` does?

```
class MyApp {

    interface X {

        fun <Q : Any, A : Any> method1(argStr: String = "", argQ: Q, argH: (A) -> Unit)

        fun <Q : Any, A : Any> method2(argQ: Q, argStr: String = "", argH: (A) -> Unit)
    }

    fun test(x: X) {

        /* Call to method1 does not work - the following errors are produced
         * Error: Kotlin: Type inference failed:
         * fun <Q : Any, A : Any> method1(argStr: String = ..., argQ: Q, argH: (A) -> Unit): Unit
         * cannot be applied to (Int,(Int) -> Unit)
         * Error: Kotlin: The integer literal does not conform to the expected type String
         * Error: Kotlin: No value passed for parameter 'argQ'
         */
        
        x.method1(1) { res: Int -> println(res) }

        /* No errors here */
        x.method2(1) { res: Int -> println(res) }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a default parameter precedes a parameter with no default value, **the default value can only be used by calling the function with named arguments**.

Example:

```
fun foo(bar: Int = 0, baz: Int) { ... }

foo(baz = 1) // The default value bar = 0 is used
```

In your example this will work:

```
x.method1(argQ = 1) { res: Int -> println(res) } // The default value argStr = "" is used
```

[Further reading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to place a parameter with a default value before a regular parameter (no default value). However, you have to keep in mind the following:

1. The value for the regular parameter will be required, so the caller will be forced to  always provide a value for the parameter with default argument which makes meaningless the purpose of having a default argument. The following will work:

```kotlin
x.method1("", 1) { res: Int -> println(res) }
```

2. The caller may skip the default parameter if they use named arguments. This is the reason the following works:

```kotlin
x.method1(argQ = 1) { res: Int -> println(res) }
```

*It is always a good idea to put parameters with default parameters in trailing positions unless the last parameter stands for a lambda expression.*